C# WPF приложение Wine - не работает TCP client
C# WPF приложение запускается под Wine на Astra Linux. Суть такова, что приложению необходимо пропинговать устройство с известным IP адресом, потом в случае если ответ на пинг пришел, попытаться к нему подключиться через TCP сокет по 1460 порту. Соединение, пинг асинхронные. Под виндой все работало, под Astra Linux через Wine ни пинги не ходят. У программы есть еще фишка - найти данное устройство в сети через бродкастный UDP поиск - здесь все работает и устройство обнаруживается.
В чем может быть дело? Коллбэк на пинг никаких ошибок не выдает, но ping reply оказывается null:
PingReply reply = e.Reply;
if (reply == null)
return;
на этом месте и выкидывает.

Приложение ваше? Если да включите отладку сети, и смотрите что там не так.

Да, мое. Только можно поподробнее?

Например Putty работает.

Фаервол проверяйте

Ситуация такая - не работал ping, так как не было доступа к RAW сокетам. Для ping-а установили привилегию cap_set_raw, ping сам по себе заработал. Также такую привилегию поставили для wine и для исполняемого файла. Но программный ping так и не работает, выкидывает ошибку: 0128:err:winediag:WSASocketW Failed to create a socket of type SOCK_RAW, this requires special permissions. Под root все работает нормально.
